# Ionic 2 page module segment optional params?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using ionic page module like this...

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'forgotten-password',
  segment: 'forgotten-password/:email/:code',
  defaultHistory: [ 'home' ]
})
```

The problem is without providing params, the url looks like this:

http://localhost:8100/#/forgotten-password/:email/:code

How can I omit the :email and :code from the route when they are not provided?

Comment: Are you building a web app?

Comment: Yes it’s a web app. Just using contents of www on build

Comment: Seem like there is no way to do this because Ionic do not care about URL. Maybe you should use angular route instead